# loading to bottom of loaded content js

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have this html code:

```
<div class="chat-messages p-4" id="messagesContainer">
   <!-- Messages will be dynamically added here -->
</div>
```

and this javascript function:

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    const lastMessage = messagesContainer.lastElementChild;
    lastMessage.scrollIntoView();
}
```

which is called upon page load. The `messagesContainer` holds the messages in which are being loaded from my database, and calling this `scrollToBottom()` function allows me to automatically scroll to the bottom of the messages, the most recent to be exact. However, the scroll animation is really ugly, it scrolls to the bottom of hundreds of messages. I am looking for a more elegant solution similar to the likes of iMessage on iPhone and Mac, where it just opens up to the most recent messages. I can add more code if needed, but looking for some advice!

Comment: What kind of animation do you actually have? And how is it implemented? Is it with CSS such as `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }` or is it done in JavaScript?

Comment: @PatrickJanser wow that's crazy, I cannot believe I overlooked that. I had added the smooth scroll-behavior a while back and totally forgot about it, as it was sitting deep in my css. Such a stupid easy fix, thank you